# HTML Upload Form Resetting After innerHTML change

Tags: javascript, html

I have an upload form

```
<form id="uploadForm" >
<input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple>
<input type="button" onclick="foo()">
</form>
```

With javascript

```
<script>
    function foo()
    {
    console.log(document.getElementById('fileInput').files.length); // check number of files
    document.getElementById('uploadForm').innerHTML += "<p>Additional Paragraph</p>"; // make a change to the innerHTML
    console.log(document.getElementById('fileInput').files.length); // check number of files again
    }
</script>
```

After i choose a file and then click the button, I get console result:

```
1
0
```

Or if i choose multiple files and click button I get console result result:

```
5
0
```

It appears that the form is resetting whenever I make a change to the innerHTML.  `<input type="file">` is being reset.  Workaround to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify html, because whole html content will be initialized again. Use something like:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput'),
p = document.createElement('P');
p.innerHTML = 'Something';
fileInput.parentNode.insertBefore(p, fileInput.nextSibling);
```

Answer (score -1):

The form is submitting and thus reloading.

There are three common fixes.

<strike>**Option 1:** change the `<input>` to a `<button type="button>`.  Those don't submit the form.</strike>

```
<form id="uploadForm" >
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple>
  <button type="button" onclick="foo()">Click me</button>
</form>
```

**Just re-read the docs.. input type="button" doesn't submit the form**

**Option 2:** Fix your JavaScript syntax error, and add `return false`

```
<script>
    function foo()
    {
      console.log(document.getElementById('fileInput').files.length); // check number of files
      document.getElementById('uploadForm').innerHTML += "<p>Additional Paragraph</p>";
      console.log(document.getElementById('fileInput').files.length); // check number of files again

      // **ADDED RETURN FALSE AND CLOSING }
      return false;
    }
</script>
```

**Option 3:** Prevent the form from every submitting through an input.

```
<form id="uploadForm" onsubmit="return false;>
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple>
  <input type="button" onclick="foo()">
</form>
```

Comment: Changed button and it had no effect.
Return false had no effect.
onsubmit="return false" had no effect.

Tried all three together and it had no effect.